# How to return multiple objects in java given a certain parameter

Tags: java, arraylist, return

The method below takes in a `starRating` from a user and searches the Array to match that rating. When the value matches one of the objects it should return it. Although the method works it only returns one `Movie` object that it finds, not every single one. For example if I enter 3 it returns the first movie that has a star rating of 3 then does not do anything. Also how can I return an empty list if the star rating does not exist? I've done a bit of research and I can't seem to find anything that helps. Thanks.

```
/**
 * Write a method that returns a list of movies with the given star rating.
 * Return an empty list if the star rating does not exist.
 */
public Movie getMoviesWithRating(int rating)
{
    for (Movie movies : movies){
        if(movies.getStarRating() == rating){
            return movies;
        }
    }
    return //EmptyList
}
```

Comment: Well, the comment says to return a list.  Maybe try that?

Comment: is that a java8 exercise?? can you use lambdas??

Comment: how you defined movies

Answer (score 1):

If you have Java 8 you can simply do it like this:

```
public List<Movie> getMoviesWithRating(int rating) {
    return movies.stream().filter(movie -> movie.rating == rating).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have a return type of List to return list of movies.

```
public List<Movie> getMoviesWithRating(int rating)
{
    List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    for (Movie movies : movies){
        if(movies.getStarRating() == rating){
            movies.add(movie);
        }
    }
    return movies.
}
```

and if you can't change the return type, at leat return a null value if no movie found with a given rating.

```
public Movie getMoviesWithRating(int rating)
{
    for (Movie movies : movies){
        if(movies.getStarRating() == rating){
            return movie;
        }
    }
    return null.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:

```
public List<Movie> getMoviesWithRating(int rating)
{
    List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    for (Movie movies : movies){
        if(movies.getStarRating() == rating){
            movies.add(movie);
        }
    }
    return movies.
}
```

If you are working with `Java 8` you can try:

```
public List<Movie> getMoviesWithRating(int rating) {
    return movies.stream().filter(movie -> movie.rating == rating).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

A better approach might be to throw an `exception` if no item is found:

```
public Movie getMoviesWithRating(int rating){
    for(final Movie movie : Movie){
         if (movie.getRating() == rating) {
             return movie;
         }
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> This Might help u out to build your Logic. Thank You.. Hope for d best :)

```
 public ArrayList<Movie> getMoviesWithRating(int rating)
    {
      ArrayList<Movie> obj_arrMovie = new ArrayList<Movie>();
        for (Movie obj_movies : movies){ //Iterate throughout the movies Array.
            if(obj_movies.getStarRating() == rating){ //Conditional Statement to check whether it is equivalent to rating or not ?.
                 obj_arrMovie.add(obj_movies); //Add all movie object to arraylist which can pass the condition.
            }
        }
        return obj_arrMovie;
    }
```

Comment: sorry i didn't see the return type of method. Now i think its work. i was Only focusing to logic area, its a mistake .
Thank You